# Does installing and re-installing my own app affect my app's rating/ranking?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, app-ratings

I just released my first app not too long ago. To test it in the Play store, I installed my own app. After discovering some bugs, I uninstalled it, and installed the one I would code to fix from Eclipse. After fixing the bug, I post an update and re-install my own app from the store to test it out again.

If I keep repeating this process (uninstalling and re-installing my own app from Google Play every time I release a new version), will my app's rating be degraded? Should I strictly stick to using my own app by installing the raw version (not the one on Google Play, but the one I built in Eclipse)?

Thanks.

Comment: As per this site [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), your question, while interesting, is considered off-topic.

Comment: @Zuul Sorry about that, I should have been more careful. It won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this should in no affect your app's rating. This is something I do myself constantly with testing of my own apps.

The only thing that will ultimately affect your rating are the number of stars your users give you. Yes, you can rate your own app, but you can only do it once. Uninstalling/re-installing shouldn't change your own rating to your own app either.

Comment: Thanks. What if I use a Google account separate from my developer account to do the testing? So my developer account is registered under one address, whereas the account I am using to do the uninstalling and re-installing is another.

Comment: @capcom should be the same effect. Active users may have a small effect on ranking in Google, but one user won't make much of a dent in regard to that. And even then, it'll still be one active user (you're just re-installing a lot).